# nm-applet openvpn connects only as root

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, openvpn

I have a following problem, network-manager doesn't connect to vpn using openvpn, when I run it as a unpriviledged user. when I run sudo nm-applet and the choose to connect to vpn it works fine.

similarily, when I run openvpn from command line it also has to be run with sudo to work.

now I'm using Arch Linux, before I switched I was using ubuntu, and I could connect to vpn using nm-applet so it is possible :)

I'd be grateful for any suggestions